# Is there a way customize MudBlazor component MudTextField with rounded corner?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I'm working with a project using Blazor WebAssembly I used the MudBlazor for my UI components. I just wondered some components are not working when I try to used the class keyword "rounded-xl" or "rounded-lg" like this in text fields.

Example:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="TextValue" Label="Outlined" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Class="rounded-xl"></MudTextField>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either set this style.

```
.mud-input-outlined-border { 
    border-radius: 24px !important; 
}
```

or you can override default theme values in **MainLayout.razor** to change default `border-radius` for all components.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div style="height: 100vh">
    <MudThemeProvider IsDarkMode="false" Theme="_customTheme" />
    <MudDialogProvider />
    <MudSnackbarProvider />
    
    @Body

</div>

@code
{

    private readonly MudTheme _customTheme = new()
    {
        LayoutProperties = new LayoutProperties()
        {
            DefaultBorderRadius = "24px",
        }
    };

}
```

Check these links for more info: [Mud Theming](https://mudblazor.com/customization/default-theme#mudtheme-typography) and [Discussion](https://mudblazor.com/customization/default-theme#mudtheme-typography)

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple to do (for some elements, at least) using the `rounded` helper class.

I am setting a MudIconButton to be completely round by using `rounded-xl`, which sets the border-radius to 24px.

```html
<MudIconButton Class="rounded-xl" />
```

More details on available options at [Border Radius](https://mudblazor.com/utilities/border-radius) doc page.